# Nosetests closes before I can read what it says

Tags: python, windows, shell, powershell

I'm running Windows 7 and am trying to run nosetests.

It's been installed and I can run it successfully, except that when I do run it (by typing 'nosetests' in the powershell window), it'll open a new cmd window with the output - but this window closes before I can see what it says. How do I prevent the results from closing so I can see them?

Comment: What happens when you run it from cmd.exe? Is it a batch script or exe?

Comment: Related question, still no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181490/powershell-suddenly-opens-cmd-exe-for-executing-bats

Comment: I say the above is related because it runs fine for me and doesn't open up a new cmd window to run. The output is in current console, as is normal.

Comment: When I run it from cmd.exe it works perfectly fine; the output prints in the window I've opened. It's only in powershell that I'm having this problem. It is an exe.

Comment: What happens when you use `nosestests -s` or `nosetests --pdb`?

Comment: The same thing; another window opens and before I can read it, it closes.

Comment: Nosetest should working fine in powershell, I had similar problem, and this one from serverfault eventually help me make it working, http://serverfault.com/questions/402083/why-powershell-runs-executables-in-separate-window

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with nosetests... would either of these work?

```
cmd /k "nosetests"
```

or

```
cmd "nosetests & pause"
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmd /c` or `cmd /k` works for me, both `nosetests` and `pip` are working, but I have to supply the full path.
see [Powershell why popup window, how to stop it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134082/powershell-why-popup-window-how-to-stop-it/12134408#12134408)

Sorry, I was meant to post a comment regarding Justin's answer.