# Powershell why popup window, how to stop it

Tags: powershell-2.0

Not sure why when I execute a Python tools like `pip` or `nosetests` inside powershell, a separate popup command line windows will show, execute my command, then disappeared. This is annoying because I can hardly see the executable output, especially the last few lines before the popup close.

I assume there are some setting I can change to stop the popup?

I am using Powershell 2.0 in Windows 7.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/03/show-powershell-hide-powershell.aspx

Comment: @Robert, I think my initial question wasn't clear. what I want is when I execute an command line tool, it is executed inside my current powershell and output to that powershell. But currently, they seems executed in a new windows command line window and disappear when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell is not cmd.exe, and it has a different console interface.  More than likely, your py tools are writing to a non-existent shell window.  You may be able to get around this by using the following syntax:

`cmd /c script.py`

What you do when you execute the python scripts directly from the PS prompt is fire-off a DOS shell for the period of time it takes for the command to complete.  Since there's no 'pause' implemented, the shell window closes when the command completes.

A test script

```
# tester.py, just a test
print "This is a test script, that is all."
```

Output in PS:

```
C:\src\python
{powem} [36] --> .\tester.py
C:\src\python
{powem} [37] --> cmd /c .\tester.py
This is a test script, that is all.
```

mp

Comment: Unfortunately, both `pip` and `nosetests` are both binary executable. `pip.exe` 'nosetests.exe` etc.

Comment: `cmd /c c:\Python27\scripts\nosetests.exe` works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For someone has similar problem, please have a look at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/402083/why-powershell-runs-executables-in-separate-window), I think this solution eventually solved my problem. and in my case, I have to restart my computer to get it all working.